# Cross-Browser JS elements

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I've tested this code in Firefox 22, Opera 12.12, Chrome 28.0.1500.95 m, and IE 8.0.6001.18702.  All in Windows XP 32 bit.  I am just wanting to know if there are any cross-browser or cross-OS issues with my code.  I am unsure how to test older versions of browsers without downgrading myself and I am unable to test mobile browsers and newer browsers.

Here is a fiddle with code below.  Click small images to make them bigger and big images to make them small.

http://jsfiddle.net/UQgWb/

```
function bigSmall(input){
    var blnMakeBig=false;
    if(input.name=="s"){
        blnMakeBig=true;
    }
    var bigImages=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i=0;i<bigImages.length;i++){
        if(bigImages[i].getAttribute("name")=="b"){
            bigImages[i].src=bigImages[i].src.substr(0,bigImages[i].src.length-bigImages[i].src.length)+"http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/top-5-cat-allergy-symptoms-2.jpg";
            bigImages[i].className="s";
            bigImages[i].name="s";
        }
    }
    if(blnMakeBig){
        input.src=input.src.substr(0,input.src.length-input.src.length)+"http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/071/7/2/grumpy_cat_trikky_by_reverendbonobo-d5xs0z6.jpg";
        input.name="b";
        input.className="b";
    }
}
```

I knot the `input.src.length-input.src.length` is unnecessary, but in the end it will be `input.src.length-5` so I left it in there for complet-ness.

I suppose the base question would be:

Are `.className`, `.name`, `.src`, `.substr()`, `.getAttribute("name")`, and `.getElementsByTagName("img")` compatible across all browsers, desktop and mobile?

I've looked at http://caniuse.com but am not having much luck there.

Comment: *I am unsure how to test older versions of browsers without downgrading myself* Virtual Machines! Microsoft even provides developer-friendly images with several combinations of Windows+IE. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575

Comment: @bfavaretto That includes IE9.  How does that work on XP?

Comment: That being said, [`getAttribute` is IE8+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752280(v=vs.85).aspx), the rest of your code is fine.

Comment: I kinda linked to a random download, but MS used to provide more options (like XP + IE6, etc); not sure if they're still around.

Comment: ... but of course the only way to be 100% sure is by testing on each target environment. Which takes us back to virtual machines! :)

Comment: Microsoft is now also providing virtual machines for all versions of IE here: http://www.modern.ie/en-us